# windows phone developer registration Tool in windows 8 operating system

Tags: windows-phone-8

I connect my phone with a pc.
Windows Phone Application in PC starts up and i can see all my photos and videos over there.

But as i start **Windows Phone Developer Registration for registration**. i get a **Register** Button, as i click on it. A Sign in screen appears for a second and gets off.
I want to deploy and test my application on a device.

Device : Nokia Lumia 520 ( **Windows Phone 8** )
PC : Windows 8 Operating System.

Comment: Do you have a developer account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was because Internet Explorer was not set to a default browser, but as i set it to Default Browser all process went successfully... :)